How to use Shell or Ansible to obtain PID from text file content?
How to obtain the value of PID？And change format to:
pid: 12032
pid: 11948 

File Content：
# cat /tmp/log.txt 
["", "whoami", "Copyright2024", "", "", "git.exe            pid: 12032  type: File           164: E:\\tmp\\", "git.exe            pid: 11948  type: File           12C: E:\\tmp\\"]


PID of other processes? we usually use ps

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use following code to extract pid from the given text
---
- name: To get PID from log.txt
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  tasks:
    - name: Extract  PID
      shell: "grep -o 'pid: [0-9]\\+' /tmp/log.txt > /tmp/pid.txt"


What you can try to use a combination of grep and read in a shell script to get the value of PID from your txt file.
grep -o 'pid: [0-9]\+' /tmp/log.txt | while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done

